# Backbone this.el jQuery

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to set up a Backbone application. This code below gives to following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'append'

```
define(
    [
        'jQuery',
        'Underscore',
        'Backbone',
        'text!templates/start.html'
    ],

    function ($, _, Backbone, startTemplate)
    {
        var StartView = Backbone.View.extend({

            // properties
            el: $('#container'),

            initialize: function ()
            {
                this.render();
            },

            render: function ()
            {
                var template = _.template( startTemplate );
                this.el.append( template );
            }
        });

        return new StartView;
    }

);
```

But this works (see the 'render'-function):

```
define(
    [
        'jQuery',
        'Underscore',
        'Backbone',
        'text!templates/start.html'
    ],

    function ($, _, Backbone, startTemplate)
    {
        var StartView = Backbone.View.extend({

            // properties
            el: $('#container'),

            initialize: function ()
            {
                this.render();
            },

            render: function ()
            {
                var template = _.template( startTemplate );
                $(this.el).append( template );
            }
        });

        return new StartView;
    }

);
```

I am passing $('#container') as the 'el'-property, so I supposed this should just work fine. Why do I have to use the jQuery notation again for this eg. $(this.el) instead of this.el

Many many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Backbone, you simply supply the ID or class name to `el`:

```
el: '#container'
```

Then, `this.el` references the DOM element, and (if you're using the latest Backbone), `this.$el` references the jQuery object.

If your Backbone is up to date, $(this.el) is not necessary

Comment: Actually supplying the DOM node in the view itself by hard-coding in the ID makes the code demonstrably less reusable. Backbone automatically sets `this.el` for you if you pass it into your views constructor (inversion of control) and also aids you in writing tests for your code as you can use an HTML Element rather than a DOM node.

`var myView = new MyView({ el: '#container' }); // Will have the same affect `